# R: pass index of 3D array using variable

Tags: r

I have a 3D array:

```
a <- array(rnorm(50*60*23), dim = c(50, 60, 23))
```

I want to set a variable that will extract the middle cuboid. Specifically, I want to use a R variable (object) to call the following cuboid:

```
a[5:41,6:51,11:19]
```

So, I want to set a R object zz which contains these indices, so that I may use

`a[zz]` to call this middle cuboid.

How do I do this? TIA.

Comment: Your third indice gets out of bound, you're taking ``1:39`` having only ``23`` defined

Comment: Ooops, sorrry, my mistake. edited.

Comment: Your edited code should work now?

Comment: No, I want to call the indices by means of a variable. Specifically, i want to define a variable (say, z, such that z contains the indices). I will edit to clarify, sorry.

Comment: with ``zz <- list(5:41,6:51,11:19)``, ``do.call(function(...)extract(a,...),zz)`` may do the trick, probably not the best solution though

Comment: @Nutle `do.call("[", c(list(a), zz))`

Comment: Thank you, @Roland, this works. If you want me to give you credit, if you put in an answer, I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you, @Nutle, the extract function, if from the raster package, gives an error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"array", "integer"’

Comment: ``extract`` was from ``magrittr`` package, often loaded together with other tidyverse packages. Though it's just an alias to ``"["`` [and the likes](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/magrittr/versions/1.5/topics/extract)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as very helpfully provided by @Roland, is:

```
a <- array(rnorm(50*60*23), dim = c(50, 60, 23))
zz <- list(5:41,6:51,11:19)
do.call("[", c(list(a), zz))
```

@Nutle also very helpfully provides the following:

```
a <- array(rnorm(50*60*23), dim = c(50, 60, 23))
zz <- list(5:41,6:51,11:19)
do.call(function(...)magrittr::extract(a,...),zz)
```

which is essentially the same as the first, since `magrittr::extract()` is just an alias to `"["`.